# Angular Directive Error Reseting on Key Down

Tags: forms, angular6

I've been trying to add form validation via a directive I have attached to a field. The directive gets call on keyup and blur. Currently when the error criteria is met an error is set but I ran into an issue where entering another key would cause the error message to flash (disappear and reappear).

Watching the elements in the console. I can see that on Key down (press/hold) my directive is not called yet but some how the ngvalid class is added to the input and the error message is cleared. Letting up on the key triggers my directive and resets the error. I've tried different logic on the error toggle in the html but the end results the same. If I was to removed the keyup listener and strictly run with blur I'd get a similar result: enter bad value -> click out of input causes error -> refocus and keydown causes the error to vanish.

Component HTML

```
<div [formGroup]="group">
    <label for="item?.keyName" class="input-label">{{item?.titleText}}</label>
    <input
        id="item?.keyName"
        name="name"
        type="text"
        data-id="textInput"
        [placeholder]="item?.placeHolder"
        zipCodeValidator
        [formControlName]="item?.keyName"
        required>

    <span [hidden]="!group.get(item?.keyName).dirty && !group.get(item?.keyName).errors?.zipCode">
          {{group.get(item?.keyName).errors?.zipCode}}
    </span>
</div>
```

Directive

```
import {Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, NgControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[zipCodeValidator]',
})

export class ZipCodeValidator {
    private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^(?:\d{5})?$/);
    private errorMessages = {
        badRegex: 'Enter a valid 5-digit US zip code. E.g. 48226.',
        emptyValue: 'Please enter a value.',
    };

    constructor(private control: NgControl) {}

    @HostListener('keyup')
    public onKeyUp(): void {
        this.validateZipCode();
    }

    @HostListener('blur')
    public onBlur(): void {
        this.validateZipCode();
    }

    private validateZipCode(): void {
        const formControl: AbstractControl = this.control.control;
        let errorMessage: string = null;

        if (!formControl.value) {
            errorMessage = this.errorMessages.emptyValue;
        }

        if (!this.regex.test(formControl.value)) {
            errorMessage = this.errorMessages.badRegex;
        }

        formControl.setErrors({ zipCode: errorMessage });
    }
}
```

The expected result is that when an error is set, the error message should remain and not be cleared by any other event besides the directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have no idea why `keyup` event is causing such behavior. But using `input` event instead of `keyup` will give you desired behavior.

```js
@HostListener('input')
public onKeyUp(): void {
    this.validateZipCode();
}
```

one more thing;

`validateZipCode()` function will set `{ zipCode: null }` on `formControl.erros` when the zip code is valid. However this will still cause formControl to be invalid. 
`validateZipCode()` shouldn't set anything when zip code is valid.

```js
  private validateZipCode(): void {
    const formControl: AbstractControl = this.control.control;
    let errorMessage: string = null;

    if (!formControl.value) {
      errorMessage = this.errorMessages.emptyValue;
    }

    if (!this.regex.test(formControl.value)) {
      errorMessage = this.errorMessages.badRegex;
    }

    if (!errorMessage) return;

    /** if there are other errors we preserve them */
    if(formControl.errors)
      formControl.setErrors({...formControl.errors, zipCode: errorMessage });
    else
      formControl.setErrors({ zipCode: errorMessage });
  }
```

here is a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ydsheq

Besides all, i strongly suggest using [Custom Validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) which is Angular way of handling form validation, and it will keep you away from such side effects. And it ll require less code. For example;

```js
  zipCodeValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^(?:\d{5})?$/);
    if (!control.value) return { zipCode: "Please enter a value." };
    if(!regex.test(control.value)) return { zipCode: 'Enter a valid 5-digit US zip code. E.g. 48226.' };
    return null;
  }

  formCtrl = new FormControl("", [Validators.required, this.zipCodeValidator]);
```

here is a working demo for custom form validators https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7xryz

Comment: To clarify, keyup works as expected. If I was to removed the keyup listener and strictly run with blur id get a similar result: enter bad value -> click out of input causes error -> refocus and keydown causes the error to vanish.

Comment: ok i think i misinterpreted your question. now, i understand that you want to use `zipCodeValidator` side-by-side with angular `Validators` such as `Validators.required`. So that, when `zipCodeValidator` is run the error from `Validators.required` which is `{required: true}` shouldn't disappear. and erros should be like `{required: true; zipCode: 'Enter a valid 5-digit US zip code. E.g. 48226.'}` did i understand it correctly?

Comment: i have updated my answer according to my comment above. now `zipCodeValidator`  doesn't remove other errors. However, i strongly suggest using custom validators approach (see example above) because using a directive may cause unexpected behavior in FormControl validity status.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'll give your solution a try here in a minute. I didn't understand why the error was getting cleared momentarily but after reading your comment above, I think you might be right.

Comment: No luck still. Something appears to clear the error before the directive runs. Am I maybe missing something built into Angular forms? Can the custom validators be called by different events like onBlur/keyUp? I'm doing different validation per event.

Comment: that’s not normal because in the stackblitz i crated above it works fine. there must be something else. what do you think about using custom validator instead of directive? also i am gonna ask you to share relevant part of your code. the part that you create/initialize the formgroup.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe I found the issue. So manually setting the error with the directive without actually assigning a validator will cause the error to get removed when the input is changed because the form updates and angular re-runs validation checks. Setting a validator and moving the existing validation logic into that method resolves the issue. This code can defiantly be cleaned up further but I think it gets the point across. So @ysf was correct when he recommended custom validators. Thank you so much for the help!

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[zipCodeValidator]',
})

export class ZipCodeValidator {
    constructor(private control: NgControl) {}

    @HostListener('keyup')
    public onKeyUp(): void {
        this.validateZipCode();
    }

    @HostListener('blur')
    public onBlur(): void {
        this.validateZipCode();
    }

    private validateZipCode(): void {
        const formControl: AbstractControl = this.control.control;
        formControl.setValidators([this.testVal]);
    }

    private testVal(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: string } | null {
        const regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^(?:\d{5})?$/);
        const errorMessages = {
            badRegex: 'Enter a valid 5-digit US zip code. E.g. 48226.',
            emptyValue: 'Please enter a value.',
        };

        let errorMessage: string = null;

        if (!control.value) {
            errorMessage = errorMessages.emptyValue;
        }

        if (!regex.test(control.value)) {
            errorMessage = errorMessages.badRegex;
        }

        return { 'zipCode': errorMessage };
    }
}
```